# Autodesk Forge: What is the difference between dbId, objectId, and nodeId?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

What is the difference between dbId, objectId, and nodeId?
For example, the first argument of the following functions is the same kind of id or ids?

- fitToView(objectIds,model)
  objectIds: array of Ids, or null.
- getProperties(dbId,onSuccessCallback,onErrorCallback)
  dbId: ID of the node to return the properties for.
- select(dbids,selectionType)
  dbids: You can pass an array of IDs or just a single ID.
- hideById(nodeId)
  nodeId: (no description)

from Viewer API reference [here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually the same, just some discrepancies about the doc.