# Properties' dbId from Viewer3D:getProperties not matching objectid from the model derivative endpoint

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

[`Viewer3d::getProperties`](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#getproperties-dbid-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) does not return all available properties when using the current test environment for SVF2 anymore. For example the property `Element ID->Value` is not available in the viewer but is available in the data returned by `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/regions/eu/designdata/:urn /metadata/:guid/properties`. My problem is that we accessed a storey node by IfcGuid via the IfcBuildingStorey node under `<No Level>` which does not work anymore (Maybe because of the new layer manager?). Does the layer manager support IfcGuid or how do I get the properties in the viewer?

#### Edit:

I found out that some `objectid`s from the properties endpoint do not match the `dbId`s in the viewer. To my knowledge they should be the same, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47354477/4295853). <s>Does someone know why?</s> SVF2's dbId do not match SFV1's dbId. It was advised to use externalId instead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64486866/how-to-match-objectids-from-autodesk-model-derivative-api-metadata-with-forge-vi?rq=1)

#### Examples:

Viewer options:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({
            'env': 'MD20ProdEU', //svf2
            'api': 'D3S', //svf2
},...
```

Original properties from calling the properties endpoint:

```json
{
   "objectid":81443,
   "name":"11. OG",
   "externalId":"0/0/0/15",
   "properties":{
      "Element ID":{
         "Value":"47823"
      },
      "Item":{
         "Hidden":"No",
         "Icon":"Layer",
         "Layer":"11. OG",
         "Material":"",
         "Name":"11. OG",
         "Required":"No",
         "Source File":"190719_Cule_Revit_Structure.ifc",
         "Type":"Levels: Level: Level 1"
      }
   }
}
```

Properties returned by `Viewer3d::getProperties`

```json
[
   {
      "displayName":"child",
      "displayValue":81444,
      "displayCategory":"__child__",
      "attributeName":"child",
      "type":11,
      "units":null,
      "hidden":1,
      "precision":0
   },
   {
      "displayName":"parent",
      "displayValue":4,
      "displayCategory":"__parent__",
      "attributeName":"parent",
      "type":11,
      "units":null,
      "hidden":1,
      "precision":0
   },
   {
      "displayName":"viewable_in",
      "displayValue":"190719_Cule_Revit_Structure.ifc",
      "displayCategory":"__viewable_in__",
      "attributeName":"viewable_in",
      "type":20,
      "units":null,
      "hidden":1,
      "precision":0
   },
   {
      "displayName":"node_flags",
      "displayValue":2,
      "displayCategory":"__node_flags__",
      "attributeName":"node_flags",
      "type":2,
      "units":null,
      "hidden":1,
      "precision":0
   },
   {
      "displayName":"Name",
      "displayValue":"11. OG",
      "displayCategory":"Item",
      "attributeName":"Name",
      "type":20,
      "units":null,
      "hidden":false,
      "precision":0
   },
   {
      "displayName":"Type",
      "displayValue":"Levels: Level: Level 1",
      "displayCategory":"Item",
      "attributeName":"Type",
      "type":20,
      "units":null,
      "hidden":false,
      "precision":0
   },
   {
      "displayName":"Icon",
      "displayValue":"Layer",
      "displayCategory":"Item",
      "attributeName":"Icon",
      "type":21,
      "units":null,
      "hidden":false,
      "precision":0
   },
   {
      "displayName":"Hidden",
      "displayValue":0,
      "displayCategory":"Item",
      "attributeName":"Hidden",
      "type":1,
      "units":null,
      "hidden":false,
      "precision":0
   },
   {
      "displayName":"Required",
      "displayValue":0,
      "displayCategory":"Item",
      "attributeName":"Required",
      "type":1,
      "units":null,
      "hidden":false,
      "precision":0
   },
   {
      "displayName":"Material",
      "displayValue":"",
      "displayCategory":"Item",
      "attributeName":"Material",
      "type":20,
      "units":null,
      "hidden":false,
      "precision":0
   },
   {
      "displayName":"Source File",
      "displayValue":"dummy.ifc",
      "displayCategory":"Item",
      "attributeName":"Source File",
      "type":20,
      "units":null,
      "hidden":false,
      "precision":0
   },
   {
      "displayName":"Layer",
      "displayValue":"11. OG",
      "displayCategory":"Item",
      "attributeName":"Layer",
      "type":20,
      "units":null,
      "hidden":false,
      "precision":0
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new temporary workaround to map between SVF1 and SVF2 dbIds provided by Autodesk:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/temporary-workaround-mapping-between-svf1-and-svf2-ids

Answer (score 0):

SVF2 uses its own DbId mapping between SVF2 and SVF1, and the `GET properties` endpoint is using SVF1 DbId as objectId, so it's why the dbId mismatched. I logged a wishlist item (LMV-5782) last week to our engineering to allocate time to evaluate the possibility of getting SVF1 DbId on the SVF2 model.

If you can get `IfcGUID` from `GET properties` endpoint by passing SVF1 DbId, then it's the case I mentioned above. We apologize for any inconvenience had caused.

Comment: I think it is only necessary because to load only specific nodes we have supply `dbId`s to the loadModel function. See my other [SO-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65337708/how-can-i-load-only-specifc-objects-in-the-forge-viewer-using-sfv2). My problem is that the `Element ID -> Value` property is missing from the nodes under `<No Level>->IfcBuildingStorey` which could be used to find the corresponding node containg the storey's elements. So my question is: how can I find the corresponding node of an `IfcBuildingStorey` node if the `Element ID->Value` property does not exist?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to load elements of a specific level by element id? And what is the layer manager? is it the model structure panel or something else?

Comment: Kinda, I want to load only a specific level and not the whole model because of its size. The layer manager is a new tool provided by the forge viewer itself. For our ifc model it lets you show and hide storeys.

Comment: Ok, sorry ... I'm not aware of the layer manager extension that can be used in that way. Now we have an internal discussion with our engineering team regarding the `objected` of the GET properties endpoint for SVF2. So, I'm curious what your use case is in detail. Could you share non-confidential information with us via forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com? I can pass it to our engineering team for evaluation.

Comment: I wrote a an email describing our use case briefly.

Comment: Btw. here's a temporary workaround until the SVF1/SVF2 dbid mapping is provided by the Model Derivative service: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/temporary-workaround-mapping-between-svf1-and-svf2-ids.